# linux - created duplicate root user, cant login anymore.. what do i do?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

i became over zealous and ran the command here

http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Create-USER-with-ROOT-Privileges-in-Linux

```
useradd -ou 0 -g 0 john
passwd john
```

now i try to connect the way i usually do

```
ssh -i yok.pem root@staging.yok.com -vv
```

and I'm getting

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to staging.yok.com [23.23.77.124] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file yok.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file yok.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
```

i luckily still have one connection to the server open..  i checked my ~/.ssh folder and the files all have 600 permissions.

what do i need to do here im stuck :(

Comment: have you tried `userdel john`?

Comment: other option is to just go and remove john from /etc/passwd

Comment: yeah i deleted that user now.. i cant login as root anymore though

Comment: do you have user root in /etc/passwd?

Comment: yes i still see the root user in there

Comment: hamobi, check log of sshd daemon on server...

Comment: where do i find sshd logs?

Comment: not understanding the downvotes..

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: okay thanks i will do that

Comment: hamobi, what is your remote OS? Is it debian or ubuntu? The log may be in  /var/log/auth.log or /var/log/messages

Comment: i see this message repeated a zillion times
Jul 14 17:40:45 ytc-prod-web1 sshd[29307]: fatal: /var/empty/sshd must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.

Comment: i changed ownership on the group and that allowed me to connect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed ownership on /var/empty/sshd

```
chown root:root /var/empty/sshd
```

yayyy

Answer (score 0):

You're having an ssh key problem not a login problem, and really I'm not surprised, since most components do not expect multiple users with the same UID, which is what you created.

Your provider should have a virtual terminal interface (console not ssh), if you connect there and if you still have the original root password, it should work, then you can remove the user you created and fix everything.

Comment: not sure im following but i removed that extra user already.. at least i dont see any sign of them

Comment: If you're back to where you were originally and want to setup ssh public key authentication, you'll need to re-add the public key from the outside account to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the server for whoever you're trying to login as (root, apparently).

Comment: "not sure im following" Back in the dark ages, *nix systems had actual terminals connected to them via serial cables. These would host login sessions for users. Remote users could login via ssh or way back then telnet, which was unencrypted. While actual terminals are very rare now, they have been emulated in VMs and are generally described as "console sessions", and are handled without the ssh daemon. If you screw up ssh, the console session still works. They're used for "local" management of *nix systems.

Comment: Also make sure that the user is gone from /etc/passswd, /etc/shadow and /etc/group, If the user is gone from those places, it's gone.